# Telling the difference between a mirrored git repository and its mirrors?

Tags: git

I've set a mirror repository on an usbkey to a LAN repository:

```
git clone --mirror git@mynetwork/myrepo.git
```

The origin remote/repository is a on some PC which is only accessible to LAN, and often shut-down (it's more like a backup PC), which means I'm almost always using the usbkey remote.

If I do a `git fetch` on usbkey it overwrite the local refspec.

How can I tell the differences **before** overwriting anything ?

On a side note, I know I can use git rev-list, but it works only because I have external refspecs, eg:

```
$ git rev-list --count --left-right origin/master...master
0       1
```

Which tells me that master has one commit more than origin/master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a second remote:

```
# go back in time
git update-ref refs/heads/master master~1

git remote add second git@mynetwork/myrepo.git
git fetch second

git rev-list --count --left-right second/master...master
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. ... and I'm good to adapt my script that use rev-list to fetch second before anything.